# Troubleshooting post-boot push notification delivery failures

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

My app receives push notifications successfully if run at least once per boot both in the background and when force closed (thanks to PushKit).

If I reboot the device, I won't receive any pushes until I launch the app at least once.

How can I get this scenario working? I'm running latest Xcode and iOS (8.3)

---

If I leave the app running in the background when I reboot the device, the app still shows up in the recents menu however no pushes are received and no AppDelegate entry points are hit (that I have anyways).

- All push/notification permissions are enabled as well as `Background App Refresh`
- Background Mode Capabilities are enabled (VoIP, push, fetch)

Comment: Its all about permission i think.

Comment: I think I need to utilize background tasks: http://blog.biokoda.com/post/114315188985/ios-and-pushkit

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the app was going dormant before the callback to update credentials.

The solution was to start a background task in `didLaunchWithOptions` and end the background task in the `didUpdatePushCredentials` function.